# SQL Server SSIS Package Scheduling

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis

We have a package that we created in VS. The package executes perfectly in VS. We then saved and deployed the package to SSIS. Inside SQL Server Management Studio, the SSIS package executes perfectly when done manually. We have 2 packages that we manually execute. We are trying to schedule these 2 packages to run automatically using the SQL Server Agent. When we set up a job and schedule it, the job fails. The first step in the package fails with the error: Failed Validation and returned validation status "VS_ISBROKEN"
We think it has to do with the security on SQL Server Agent, but we have checked and all the permissions seem to be set correctly.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You should be getting additional error messages other than the VS_ISBROKEN, which will be more helpful in figuring out what's going on. It has been my experience that VS_ISBROKEN almost always refers to an invalid query. For example, the query could be referencing an object that doesn't exist on the target server.

Comment: But if that is the case, wouldn't the package fail if ran manually?

Comment: Don't you see the error? A table is missing ("Table does not exist"). This is the real error.

Comment: I see that error, but that table does exist, because i execute the package and it imports the data correctly. Is it a permission error that it cannot see/find the table?

Comment: It's possible the account being used to execute the SSIS package, when fired from a job, doesn't have necessary permissions to access the table. When you execute the package from SSMS, you are using your permissions, which, it seems, are such that you can access the required tables.

Comment: I am using the SQLSERVERAGENT to execute the job, not the user that created the package. I am logging into SSMS with my local credentials which are the same credentials used to create the package. I did try setting up a Credential inside SSMS to run the job as the same user as I do when I manually run the package and that seemed to fail as well. Maybe I set up the Credential in SSMS wrong.

Comment: It doesn't matter who created the job or the package or what their permissions are. What matters is what account is being used when the Job executes the SSIS package. This will usually be some sort of 'service' account that will need the necessary permissions (probably the same permissions you have).

Comment: Just verified that the account running the job has all the correct permissions.

Comment: Ok, well, this is not rocket science. Either the table does not physically exist or the account executing the SSIS package cannot access it. It cannot be anything else.

Comment: Agreed, that is why we are very confused, because it has to be one or the other, but we have confirmed both and set up correctly. I came to SO to see if anyone had some insight into what we might be missing. The source where the data is coming from is an ODBC connection, not sure if that matters and the credentials for that are stored in the package.

Answer (score 0):

I came across a similar problem in an earlier version of `SSMS` and found the problem was that the owner of the package in `SQL server Agent` was incorrect and should be `sa` or `dbo`

I don't know if it helps but the symptoms for this seem very similar to mine